# Convert htacces rules to web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, iis-7, web-config

Need to convert this htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir1/dir2/dir3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myscript.php [L]
```

to web.config file for IIS webserver. 
I tried this:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
<files>
<add value="myscript.php" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but this config only makes myscript.php an index file. How about rewrite base?

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can try full path to the file ...

```
<add value="/dir1/dir2/dir3/myscript.php" />
```

I hope this help !

Btw, check the path you are using...
this first backslash before path should means you are pointing for the disk root

Comment: sorry, i was wanting to mean on your add tag for your config file ... i edited the post !

Comment: No, it is not working I  made    <add value="/dir1/dir2/dir3/myscript.php" /> and get 403 error